# Frequency of live refresh

Tags: discussion, live-refresh, ajax

I've noticed the Ajax stuff that performs live refresh actions on pages has slowed down considerably. For example, reputation changes and inbox notifications are not being reflected in the top bar immediately like they were before, and votes / new comments / new answers don't seem to be coming in real time either.

I also saw orange slidey again for the first time in a long time this morning:

[image]

---

As an example, [this page has been in my browser for almost an hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274788/placement-of-withnolock-in-nested-queries):

[image]

But I happen to know that there has been activity, since I answered the question in another tab. When I hit refresh, BOOM! My reputation updates, the answers and comments pour in, an edit from 53 minutes ago appears... the votes on the question would have changed as well, except there happen to be two up and two down, so that doesn't stand out:

[image]

So, I'm just wondering, has some change taken place? I can imagine it being intentional to relieve some pressure off the APIs, or perhaps some of the APIs are currently broken.

If this is intentional, this is totally understandable, of course. I'm not complaining, and I don't want it changed or "fixed" if this was a choice - I just want to know if others have noticed it too, or if my OCD is on steroids today, or if somehow the problem might be on my side (using Chrome 28 on OS X).

Comment: I have too. It's been taking a lot more reloading lately.

Comment: I've also noticed this - just thought it was an artifact of browsing from a new browser or something.